Variation of Lagrangian for a Free Particle in Dan Freed Notes
I am having trouble convincing myself of the following line
\begin{align*}
    \delta L &=  m \langle \dot{x}, \delta \dot{x} \rangle \\
    &= -m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle - d \{m \langle \dot{x}, \delta x \rangle \} \tag{1.3}
\end{align*}
from page 143 (first page after the Introduction) of https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/79_ClassicalFieldTheory.pdf where
$$
L = \frac{m}{2} \langle \dot{x}, \dot{x} \rangle
$$
is the Lagrangian of a classical free particle and $\dot{x} = dx/dt$. What I have, from the dot product rule for differentiation and the fact that commuting $d$ past $\delta$ results in a sign change, is
\begin{align*}
    -m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle - d \{m \langle \dot{x}, \delta x \rangle \} &= -m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle - \{m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle + m \langle \dot{x}, d\delta x \rangle \} \\
    &= -m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle - \{m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle - m \langle \dot{x}, \delta \dot{x} \rangle \} \\
    &= -m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle - m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle + m \langle \dot{x}, \delta \dot{x} \rangle \\
    &= - 2m \langle \ddot{x}, \delta x \rangle + m \langle \dot{x}, \delta \dot{x} \rangle
\end{align*}
So I am off by a sign it seems. I attempted going the other direction and that did not work out either, but I'll just ask about my work in this direciton. Thanks in advance.
